# apply h3.string_to_h3 on dask.dataframe thru map_partitions

Tags: dask-dataframe, h3

I would like to ask how to use dd.map_partitions for h3.string_to_h3 function.
my dataframe looks like this

| h3 | lat | lon | x | y | elevation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 8ca80c8e91015ff | -23.068134 | -52.042272 | 393235.906794 | 7.448557e+06 |
| 3 | 8ca80c8ecadd1ff | -23.095896 | -52.031107 | 394401.401086 | 7.445492e+06 |
| 4 | 8ca80cbb455b1ff | -23.052007 | -52.055948 | 391822.030340 | 7.450333e+06 |
| 5 | 8ca80cbb6a06dff | -23.045227 | -52.049591 | 392468.007662 | 7.451088e+06 |
| 6 | 8ca80c85876e9ff | -23.077720 | -52.085169 | 388849.315388 | 7.447464e+06 |

If this is pandas, I can simply using apply function to get hexagon index, `df['h3'].apply(h3.string_to_h3)`. But how if I have a large dataset and would like to use dd.map_partitions?

I have tried `df['h3'].apply(h3.string_to_h3)`, `df['h3'].map_partitions(h3.string_to_h3, meta={'hexagons':'int64'})`, and `df['h3'].map_partitions(h3.string_to_h3, axis=1, meta={'hexagons':'int64'})`. None of them are working.

Could someone here told me how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`map_partitions`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions.html) does what it says on the tin - that is, it applies a mapping function that accepts a partition dataframe as input. You can then manipulate the partition itself inside that function.

I haven't tested the code below, but I believe this should work:

```
df['h3'] = df.map_partitions(
  lambda partition: partition['h3'].apply(h3.string_to_h3),
  meta=('h3', np.uint64),
)
```

Comment: I actually run similar stuff like this but not working. I use `meta = {'h3':int}` as the case. But I know I should use a tuple, rather than a dict.  Thank you !!